# Inject or share functionalities with side-effects between React components

Tags: reactjs, code-reuse, antd

I'm using the Table component of the [Ant Design Library](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) and I implemented my customs filters components per each column of the table. Now i want to start to use this approach for a couple of tables too. The problem is I have a set of functions where I modify the state of the filters and at the same time they are common for all the tables that use filters.

Therefore, I would not want each time I have to implement a table with filters to have to copy, paste, and finally duplicate this logic. What I would like in some way would be to create a table and somehow (using good practices) to be able to inject these functionalities for this new component.

I tried first with Higher-Order Components (HOCs), but I read in the react doc that: `A HOC is a pure function with zero side-effects`. Another option could be used Inheritance but I don't know if is going to be the best approach.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to inject and reuse common functionalities with side-effects between components?

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong to create a HOC for your purpose. A HOC takes a React class as an argument and produces an “enhanced” or richer component class that you can then instantiate. That’s all there is to it. Your HOC could take the ADL Table component and create a class of the same component plus your custom filters. Remember: your HOC creates a *class*, not a *component* instance of that class.

If you go down this route, I suggest you to have a look at https://github.com/acdlite/recompose.